# How to install unrar-nonfree?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I installed `unrar-free`, but I cannot extract a multi-file `.rar` archive (`my_archive.part01.rar`, `my_archive.part02.rar`, etc.):

```
$ ls
my_archive.part01.rar
my_archive.part02.rar
my_archive.part03.rar
$ unrar -x my_archive.part01.rar

unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


Extracting from /home/morgan/my_archive.part01.rar

Extracting  my_text_file.txt      Failed
1 Failed
```

I have read that I need `unrar-nonfree` to manage multipart archives, but It seems it is not included in the official Raspbian repo.

How can I install `unrar-nonfree`?

Comment: This may be different than it was in 2012, but I recently installed `runrar-free` and the syntax is `unrar e -r <filename>.rar` and it will recursively extract your files.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. Uninstall `unrar-free`.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get remove unrar-free
   ```
2. Make sure you have a source repository by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

   ```
   $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
   # Default repository
   deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
   # Source repository to add
   deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
   ```
3. Sync the apt database.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Create a working directory and move into it. The `unrar-nonfree` command will be built in this directory.

   ```
   $ cd $(mktemp -d)
   ```
5. Install the dependencies required by `unrar-nonfree`.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get build-dep unrar-nonfree
   ```
6. Download the `unrar-nonfree` sources and build the `.deb` package.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get source -b unrar-nonfree
   ```
7. Install the generated `.deb` package. Its name varies depending on the version of `unrar-nonfree`.

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg -i unrar*.deb
   ```
8. The working directory you have created in step 4 will be removed at next boot; there is no use to delete it.

Once installed, you can use either `unrar` or `unrar-nonfree` (`unrar` is a simlink to `unrar-nonfree`).

Warning: `unrar-nonfree` and `unrar-free` options are different. For instance, to extract an archive:

```
$ # with unrar-free
$ unrar -x my_archive.part01.rar

$ # with unrar-nonfree
$ unrar e my_archive.part01.rar
```

Please `man unrar-nonfree` for more details.

Comment: This is a small correction to Morgan's excellent answer. Step 7 should be this: $ sudo dpkg -i unrar_4.1.4-1_armhf.deb Other than this, it's a perfect solution. Tim

Comment: Turned step #7 into `sudo dpkg -i unrar*.deb` so it doesn't depend on version number anymore.

Comment: I followed these steps exactly only to get 'E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list'. I'm certain I did do that, by adding -src to a duplicate of my existing repository. The error occurred in step five. Can anyone help?

Comment: You did entered the command `sudo apt-get update`, right? Is there any error message?

Comment: Edited the answer with a small fix: remove the compile directories is not possible because we must sudo. Also added the f flag (force) so we are not questioned "are you sure?" for each file.

Comment: Hi i am also getting error on step 5 " 'E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list'"

Answer (score 7):

`unrar-nonfree` can be installed from [Debian armhf repository](https://packages.debian.org/buster/unrar) (it's simply called `unrar` there). For example, in Raspbian Buster you can run:

```
wget -qO - https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys/archive-key-10.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

Don't forget to disable the Debian repository once you're done: it's not recommended to upgrade your system while having a Debian repository as a source.

An alternative is to install 7-zip with RAR support (though it may not work on newer or password-protected archives):

```
sudo apt install p7zip-full
```

Comment: Great answer! Easy and working!

Comment: Excellent answer but how to disable the Debian repository once done? thanks

Comment: @HendryLim Remove or comment out the `deb.debian.org` line from `sources.list`, then run `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 2):

this is my compiled unrar 4.20

[unrar_4.20_armhf.deb](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7F-GIHpyhY-X0QzRmRWcGhUem8)

eliafino

Comment: Hi there. This answer will only stay relevant for a short period of time (until unrar) is updated. We usually like answers to be able to stand on their own, which is why teaching how to compile the package is better.