# How to extract mutipart rar files?

Tags: raspbian, file

Hi i tried extracting a multi part rar files using unrar-free but it does not work and i get an error saying "failed"

I followed this guide below :

Uninstall unrar-free.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove unrar-free
```

Make sure you have a source repository by editing /etc/apt/sources.list.

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# Default repository
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
# Source repository to add
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

Sync the apt database.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Create a working directory and move into it. The unrar-nonfree command will be built in this directory.

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
```

Install the dependencies required by unrar-nonfree.

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep unrar-nonfree
```

Download the unrar-nonfree sources and build the .deb package.

```
$ sudo apt-get source -b unrar-nonfree
```

Install the generated .deb package. Its name varies depending on the version of unrar-nonfree.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i unrar*.deb
```

The working directory you have created in step 4 will be removed at next boot; there is no use to delete it.

When i edited my source.list and then do a sudo apt-get update i get this error below:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy InRelease
Err:4 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is there another tool i can use instead of this or can anybody help me fix this error?

Comment: Try using p7zip-rar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install unrar-nonfree?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/how-to-install-unrar-nonfree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is obviously some years old; `wheezy` and `buster` are distro versions, the former being no longer supported.  Your `source.list` should instead read:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian buster main contrib non-free rpi
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Ie., adding the `deb-src` and `non-free` stuff to buster, not wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding Jessie instead of weazy in the source set