# Enable /dev/ttyAMA0 on Debian (not Raspbian)

Tags: serial, debian, home-automation

I have an RaspberryPI 3+ with Debian installed on it. I'am trying to connect a serial device (Raspbee) via the GPIO pins like [this](https://phoscon.de/raspbee/img/raspbee1-header2.jpg). Under Raspbian this worked by enabling UART in `raspi-config` after which I could talk to the device via `/dev/ttyAMA0`.

How can I do this on Debian? There is of course no `raspi-config` on stock Debian and I doesn't get any communication out of `/dev/ttyAMA0`.

Comment: What does DebIan give you that's not in Raspbian or Raspbian Lite? Here's a clue: nothing except serial doesn't work.

Comment: That's not really the point here but the most important benefit of debian over raspbian is, that it comes without any non-free software. It also is way less bloated with software I don't need.

Comment: Switch to Raspbian Lite then add in things you need. That's better supported than DebIan.

Comment: @Dougie Some packages are missing, broken, or outdated in Raspbian, e.g. [`unrar-nonfree`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3617/33476) or [`perf`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/119501/33476), so Debian is not entirely useless as you suggest.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev wait until RaspiOS Bullseye comes out and try again.

Answer (score 1):

`raspi-config` is just a shell script with minimal dependencies.  Grab a copy from here:

https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config

For most things including this it should work fine as Raspbian is in fact nearly identical to Debian.  There may be a few thing that require [the userland tools](https://github.com/raspberrypi) but this is not one of them.

All it appears to to do is add `enable_uart=1` to `/boot/config.txt`, and, if you want the serial line console disabled (you probably do if you want to do anything other than login or observe system messages over UART), it removes `console=serial0` or `console=ttyAMA0` `/boot/cmdline.txt`.  The best bet is to change that to `console=tty1`, which will put system messages on a virtual console (the one you see on the screen if you boot without a GUI).

The official `config.txt` documentation regarding the UART is here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/uart.md

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you use `/dev/serial0` (which is `/dev/ttyS0` on the Pi3) `/dev/ttyAMA0` is connected to Bluetooth.

I haven't used Debian on a Pi, but assume it is using Device Tree and has the standard devices and uses `udev` to map serial ports.

NOTE to use a Pi you **MUST** use "non-free software" just to boot.

The following link explains serial, and manual processes to enable it.
[How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 or later](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)