# specific llvm version

Tags: software-installation, llvm

I have a question, how to install a specific version of llvm on raspberry pi?
I would like to install llvm-7, but `sudo apt install llvm-7` does not work.
Can someone please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: On which OS + version? Pls update your question with relevant info?

Answer (score 1):

On Buster, you could try to get `llvm-7` from the [Debian repo](https://packages.debian.org/buster/llvm-7). I wrote installation steps for [`unrar`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107472/33476) a while ago, they might work for LLVM as well.

Newer distributions don't support `llvm-7`, you'll have to build it yourself if you really need it.

Comment: llvm-7 seems to be available in the PiOS Buster repo.